# Update using minis

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hello I want to update table2 if the data does not match table 1. If there are results in the below query I would like table2 to be updated

```
Select id, name, desc
From table1
Minus 
Select id, name, desc
From table2



Table1
Id, name, desc
1   bob   green
2   Sam   Blue

Table2
Id, name,  desc
1   bob    yellow
2   sam b  Red
```

I want table2 to have the same data as table1

```
Table2
Id, name, desc
1   bob   Green
2   Sam   Blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Table2` to have the same data as `Table1` then I would recommend truncating it and re-inserting the data:

```
truncate table table2;

insert into table2(id, name, desc)
    select id, name, desc
    from table1;
```

This operation is usually going to be faster than a bunch of updates.

EDIT:

In Oracle, you can use `merge` or set the fields as:

```
update table2
    set (name, desc) = (select name, desc from table1 where table1.id = table2.id);
```

If you like, you can add:

```
where (name, desc) <> (select name, desc from table1 where table1.id = table2.id)
```

Comment: Truncating is not an option in my case unfortunately.

Comment: Wouldnt the where clause in your solution not update table2 for bob and green because bob equals table2.name? In order to mimimize the updates I will want to check if the vales equal or not

Comment: @Krev32 . . . The `where` clause would limit the updates.  In your case, though, the values are not the same because of capitalization, so all the rows would be updated.  If you don't care about `case`, you can add `lower()` to the columns in the `where` (all four).